# How to create a dynamic array using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dynamic-arrays

I'm learning Visual C++ using MFC and I need to create a dynamic int array without worry about memory location. The array size will be increasing during the run time.

```
int myArray[5]; // I want to change this as a dynamic array
int counter = 0;
int currentValue;
... more Code

void CScribbleView::OnLButtonUp(UINT, CPoint point) 
{
   myArray[counter] = currentValue;
   counter++;
   currentValue = 0;
... more Code
}
```

Comment: There are many ways. There are collection classes provided that you can use and you can also dynamically create an array of any size using `new[]` and `delete[]`. See this [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/). But I suggest using an existing array collection or `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, `std:vector` is definitely a better alternative to `CArray`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: The code in question is from the Scribble sample program. This program implements serialization support. When doing MFC serialization, `CArray` is usually a better choice, as it comes with serialization support built in.

Comment: @IInspectable all right,  I wasn't aware.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, you are right. It's a sample Scribble program. CArray is the better solution to make a dynamic array, because I'm using MFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [CArray Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct.aspx), the changes in your code will be something like:

```
CArray<int, int> myArray;
int currentValue;
... more Code

void CScribbleView::OnLButtonUp(UINT, CPoint point) 
{
   myArray.Add(currentValue);
   currentValue = 0;

... more Code
}
```